# How to seed randn function opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, random, random-seed

I want to seed randn function but I'm not able to do it.

```
srand(time(NULL));
Mat mymat = Mat::zeroes(1024,1024,CV_32F);
randn(mymat,0,1);
```

Should it not give me random mat, named `mymat`, whose `mean = 0`, and `variance = 1`? However, it gives the same `mymat` in every run.

Here is the link for [randn](http://moby.ihme.washington.edu/bradbell/mat2cpp/randn.xml) which claims srand to work.

I tried to give different numbers instead of time(NULL), but all have the same output randoms. I have checked the same thing from another machine, it gives the same output with the first machine. So seeding is not working.

Thanks,

Comment: The link you supplied says you should call `srand()` **for that example implementation**, not that `srand()` will initialise `randn()` *in general*.  Unfortunately, it doesn't tell you a guaranteed method to initialise `randn()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set seed for OpenCV functions using using the following snippet:

```
cv::theRNG().state = seed;
```

There is a subtlety for multithreaded programs - OpenCV uses thread-local random number generators so you need (re)set seed from the same thread.

Comment: My code is not multithreaded. Is it enough to use `cv::theRNG().state = time(NULL);` in `main` function? Then could I generate random matrices from other functions? If so, it is not working for `randn`.

Comment: try cv::getTickCount() instead of time(NULL)